# form_checkbox is not working in Php (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans

form_checkbox is not working in Php (Codeigniter).

```
<div class='checkbox'>
    <?php
    echo form_checkbox(array(
        'name' => 'remember',
        'id' => 'remember',
        'value' => 'Remember Me',
        'checked' => FALSE,
    ));
    ?>
</div>
```

I have to print the label with checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should be sure that you have loaded the file helper?
**Load file helper something like this :**

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

**Below code for produce checkbox:**

```
$data = array(
    'name'          => 'newsletter',
     'id'            => 'newsletter',
     'value'         => 'accept',
     'checked'       => TRUE,
     'style'         => 'margin:10px'
);
echo form_label('Checkboc Label', 'newsletter');
// Would produce:  <label for="newsletter">What is your Name</label>
echo form_checkbox($data);
```

Comment: I tried and its not working. The label is not printing.

Comment: I have update answer please check use code for display label : <?php echo form_label('Checkboc Label', 'newsletter');?>

Comment: Yes Now its working fine.  <div class='checkbox'>
    <?php
    echo form_checkbox(array(
        'name' => 'remember',
        'id' => 'remember',
        'value' => 'REMEMBER ME',
        'checked' => FALSE,
        'style' => 'margin:1px'
    )).form_label('REMEMBER ME','remember');
    
    ?>
</div>

Comment: @bhuvana If it is working correctly so pleaee accepr the answer so help others too.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to load `form` helper and then you need to `concat` your label string before the  `form_checkbox()` like below

```
<div class='checkbox'>
    <?php
    echo 'Remember Me '.form_checkbox(array(
        'name' => 'remember',
        'id' => 'remember',
        'value' => '1',
        'checked' => FALSE,
    ));
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you its working but I concatenated after the form_checkbox. <div class='checkbox'>
    <?php
    $data = array(
        'name' => 'remember',
        'id' => 'remember',
        'value' => 'REMEMBER ME',
        'checked' => FALSE,
        //'style' => 'margin:10px'
    );
    echo form_checkbox($data)."\r\r"."REMEMBER ME";
    ?>
</div>

Comment: your welcome, please accept the answer if it helps you so others can get easy help